# Making rest post request always returning 200 despite wrong credentials

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, flask

Hi so I am making a rest request after onclick action of html button. I enter the wrong info into the form and i always get 200 response code no matter what. When I test the same exact function with node in terminal i get 401 as i should- so i know its not an issue in the api i wrote.

heres the code for the web app;

```
<button id="loginButton" onclick="login_user()">login</button>


<script type="text/javascript">
function login_user() {
let path = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/resource";
let user_input = document.getElementById("user").value;
let pass_input = document.getElementById("pass").value;

let data = {username: user_input, password: pass_input};

fetch(path, {
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"},
        method: "POST", 
        body: JSON.stringify(data)}
).then((response) => {
    if (response.status == 200) {
        window.location.href = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/welcome"
    } else  if (response.status == 401) {
        window.location.href = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/login"
    }
});
};
</script>
```

whats going on here is even with the wrong info entered into the login forms, i always get 200 and so always get redirected to the welcome screen.

meanwhile I am testing this same code with node;

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

function login_user(user, pass) {
    let path = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/resource";
    let username = user;
    let password =  pass;

    let data = {username: username, password: password};

    fetch(path, {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"},
            method: "POST", 
            body: JSON.stringify(data)}
    ).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        if (response.status == 200) {
             console.log("success")
        }
        else {
            console.log("failure")
        }
    });
    };

login_user("invalidusername", "invalidpassword")
```

and this returns 401 as it should. does anyone know why this could be happening?

server side (flask) in case there is an issue in here:

```
# initialize app
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = urandom(24)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "sqlite:///db.sqlite"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_COMMIT_ON_TEARDOWN'] = True

# extensions
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
auth = HTTPBasicAuth()


class User(db.Model):
    '''secure:
        -- stores password hash
        -- option to auth via token after initial sign in'''

    __tablename__ = "users"
    # columns
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(32), index=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(64))
    email = db.Column(db.String(320))
    sign = db.Column(db.String(24))

    def hash_password(self, password):
        self.password_hash = pwd_context.encrypt(password)

    def verify_password(self, password):
        return pwd_context.verify(password, self.password_hash)

    def generate_auth_token(self, expiration=600):
        s = Serializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'], expires_in=expiration)
        return s.dumps({'id': self.id})

    @staticmethod
    def verify_auth_token(token):
        s = Serializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
        try:
            data = s.loads(token)
        except SignatureExpired:
            return None
        except BadSignature:
            return None
        user = User.query.get(data['id'])
        return user


@auth.verify_password
def verify_password(username_or_token, password):
    # use token (preferred)
    user = User.verify_auth_token(username_or_token)
    # use username
    if not user:
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username_or_token).first()
        if not user or not user.verify_password(password):
            return False
    g.user = user
    return True


@app.route('/api/users', methods=['POST'])
def new_user():
    username = request.json.get('username')
    password = request.json.get('password')
    email = request.json.get('email')
    sign = request.json.get('sign')
    # missing arguments
    if None in (username, password, email, sign):
        print('missing arguments')
        abort(400)
    # username taken
    elif User.query.filter_by(username=username).first() is not None:
        print('username taken')
        abort(400)
    # email already registered
    elif User.query.filter_by(email=email).first() is not None:
        print('email taken')
        abort(400)
    else:
        user = User(username=username, email=email, sign=sign)
        user.hash_password(password)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        return (jsonify({'username': user.username,
                         'email': user.email, 'sign': user.sign}), 201,
                        {'Location': url_for('get_user', id=user.id,
                         _external=True)})


@app.route('/api/users/<int:id>')
def get_user(id):
    user = User.query.get(id)
    if not user:
        abort(400)
    return jsonify({
        'username': user.username, 
        'email': user.email, 
        'sign': user.sign})

@app.route('/api/token')
@auth.login_required
def get_auth_token():
    token = g.user.generate_auth_token(600)
    return jsonify({'token': token.decode('ascii'), 'duration': 600})

@app.route('/api/resource', methods=['POST'])
@auth.login_required
def get_resource():
    return jsonify({
        'username': g.user.username,
        'email': g.user.email,
        'sign': g.user.sign})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if not path.exists('db.sqlite'):
        db.create_all()
    app.run()
```

Comment: Not really going to be able to help without seeing the server-side code. I know you say it works, but obviously it's only working in Node and not a browser, so there may be something in the API.

Comment: right. i can show you the server side code but its just a pretty simple flask api written in python. I just dont understand how the same exact request could return differently in a browser. I am f12-ing and looking at the request in browser and the user and pass I enter are just random letters and still returns 200.. while I only have one user account created in the sqlite db

Comment: The Node and front end code look fine, which makes me think this is an issue in Flask, not your JS code. I'm adding the Flask tag, and I encourage you to add your flask API code for that endpoint.

Comment: @jakerella went ahead and just added it all above. thanks so much for helping me out

Comment: The only thing I can think of that is that Flask may be detecting that the request is coming from a browser and then serving up the login page with a 200 response and the Node request is detected as a straight up API call and thus delivers the 401. I'm not a Flask person, so I can't really say, but I would look there. I still don't think the JS code is the problem here.

Comment: @jakerella yeah its got to be that its from the browser. Im testing the api via command line, python, node, postman, and everything is working unless its being made from the browser. cant find anything about anyone else having this issue online so might just have to use a flask alternative :/